# cannot login in to laravel project

Tags: laravel, authentication

I cant login to my system, I don't what is the problem. It doesn't show any errors but only a 404 page and this URL:

[image]

here is my login blade

```
<form action="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="email@example.com" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        @error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="masukkan password" required autocomplete="current-password">
         @error('password')
         <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
         </span>
         @enderror
      </div>
        
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block login-btn" action="{{ route('landpage') }}">
          Login
      </button>
</form>
```

controller

```
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->role; 

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 'student':
                return 'backend/profilone';
            break;
        case 'staff':
                return 'backend/profiltwo';
            break; 
        default:
                return '/home'; 
            break;
    }
}
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkRole:superadmin,admin']], function(){

Route::get('/home', 'Backend\HomeController@index')->name('home');


});
```

Comment: Share ur web.php file and the controller used

Comment: you have `action="POST"` and also `action="{{ route('login' }}` I'm sure you meant to use `method="POST"`

Comment: oh thankyou! @apokryfos

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
@csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="email@example.com" value="{{ old('email') }}">
        @error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
        
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="masukkan password" required autocomplete="current-password">
         @error('password')
         <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
         </span>
         @enderror
      </div>
        
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block login-btn" action="{{ route('landpage') }}">
          Login
      </button>
</form>

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'checkRole:superadmin,admin']], function(){

Route::get('/home', 'Backend\HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/login', 'Backend\HomeController@methodforlogin')->name('login');
});
```